# How to change telerik:RadGridView row background color on mouse hover

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm quite new to telerik controls. I'm working with a telerik:RadGridView and by default the background of the row was changed into light grayish color when the mouse cursor was hovered above that row. This makes the texts from the row hard to read. So, I was wondering is there a way to change the row background to blue instead of the light grayish color when the row's being hovered. Also, my telerik version is 2016. The following is the grid I'm working with.

```
<telerik:RadGridView
    x:Name="gridReport"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Tab.ListGraphReport}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxDataTemplate}"
    GroupPanelBackground="Transparent"
    GroupPanelForeground="White"
    RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
    ColumnWidth="*"
    Background="Transparent"
    Foreground="White"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ShowGroupPanel="False">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Indicator" IsFilterable="False">
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle
                            Height="10"
                            Width="10"
                            Fill="{Binding ColorName, Converter={StaticResource NVarToBrushConverter}}"
                            Grid.Column="0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Graph}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn
            Header="Min"
            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Min}"
            DataFormatString="{}{0:N2}"
            IsFilterable="False" >
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn
            Header="Max"
            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Max}"
            DataFormatString="{}{0:N2}"
            IsFilterable="False">
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn
            Header="AVG"
            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Avg}"
            DataFormatString="{}{0:N2}"
            IsFilterable="False">
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn
            Header="Unit"
            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Unit}"
            DataFormatString="{}{0:N2}"
            IsFilterable="False">
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: @mm8 It's Expression_DarkTheme.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to copy the default `ControlTemplate` for the `GridViewRow` from`Themes.Implicit\WPF40\ExpressionDark\Themes\Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml` and change the `Background` property of the `Background_Over` element, or the `Color` of the `ItemBackground_Over` brush:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemBackground_Over" Color="#FF565656"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me where I can find this file? I couldn't find the path.

Comment: @Trax: In the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik` folder on your computer, provided that you have installed the SDK.

Comment: @Trax: Did you try this or what happened? Please remember to aceept the answerif your original issue has been solved.

Comment: I never did find the folder because Telerik wasn't installed in my V.M. I'm 
just working with the dlls. :(

Comment: You can generate the template by right-clicking on a `GridViewRow` in Blend and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy.

Answer (score 0):

To change the mouse over background of the `RadGridView` rows, set the `MouseOverBackground` property of the `GridViewRow` controls.

```
<telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
        <Setter Property="MouseOverBackground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
```

Read more about this here: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/rows/selected-row-background

Note that, if you  use [NoXaml](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/xaml-vs-noxaml) dlls you will need to base the row style to the default `GridViewRowStyle`.

```
<telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewRowStyle}">
        <Setter Property="MouseOverBackground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Hi, Martin. Thanks for the answer. But I'm getting this error. The member "MouseOverBackground" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Comment: The MouseOverBackground property is available from version R1 2019 SP1 of Telerik UI for WPF